# See who rated list items 0-5

Tags: list, list-form, rating

I've managed to get the rating system enabled and after doing a bit of reading it looks as though if i used the like system you can see who has liked the item by hovering of the smiley face...but for this list I need to use 0-5 Stars Rating

So is there a way of checking who has rated a post 0-5 similar to the Smiley face system? - Even if it means entering a new column into the items on the list that's fine

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need the solution based on client side scripting or server side ?

Comment: @MonicaJagani It'll be client side